# Magento Create Category While Installing a Module

Tags: mysql

While creating the category via installer, category not created but the table is created,

below i added my installer script,

any wrong in this script?

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$installer->getTable('membership/members')};
CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('membership/members')}` (
      `memberid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `name` text,
      `email` text,
      `cateid` text,
      `date` datetime default NULL,
      `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`memberid`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$installer->getTable('membership/types')};
CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('membership/types')}` (
      `mtypeid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `typename` text,
      `duration` text,
      `description` text,
      `price` text,
      PRIMARY KEY (`mtypeid`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");

$allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();
foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId => $val)
{
    $_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getId();
    $root_catid = Mage::app()->getStore($_storeId)->getRootCategoryId();

    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($root_catid);
    $childCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', true)
        ->addIdFilter($parentCategory->getChildren())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('name', 'categoryname')
        ->getFirstItem()    // Assuming your category names are unique ??
    ;

    if ($childCategory->getId() == null) {
        $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
        $category->setName('categoryname');
        $category->setUrlKey('att-membership');
        $category->setIsActive(1);
        $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
        $category->setIsAnchor(0);

        $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($root_catid);
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());              

        $category->save();
        unset($category);
    } 
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Try moving the code for creating the category to the `data` folder of your module in the file `data-install-1.0.0.php`. Replace (1.0.0 with your version number)

Comment: Please write what you did as an answer and accept it. Don't leave zombie questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have split the mysql4-install-1.0.0.php into  2 files ,

modulename\sql\membership_setup\mysql4-install-1.0.0.php, shows below

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$installer->getTable('membership/members')};
CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('membership/members')}` (
      `memberid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `name` text,
      `email` text,
      `cateid` text,
      `date` datetime default NULL,
      `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`memberid`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$installer->getTable('membership/types')};
CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('membership/types')}` (
      `mtypeid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `typename` text,
      `duration` text,
      `description` text,
      `price` text,
      PRIMARY KEY (`mtypeid`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");


$installer->endSetup();
```

data file "modulename\data\membership_setup\data-install-1.0.0.php",

```
$allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();
foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId => $val)
{
    $_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getId();
    $root_catid = Mage::app()->getStore($_storeId)->getRootCategoryId();

    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($root_catid);
    $childCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', true)
        ->addIdFilter($parentCategory->getChildren())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('name', 'AttVirMembership')
        ->getFirstItem()    // Assuming your category names are unique ??
    ;

    if ($childCategory->getId() == null) {
        $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
        $category->setName('AttVirMembership');
        $category->setUrlKey('att-vir-membership');
        $category->setIsActive(1);
        $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
        $category->setIsAnchor(0);

        $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($root_catid);
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());              

        $category->save();
        unset($category);
    } 
}
```

ie. mysql query in the - mysql file and php script in the data file,

then its worked well.

thanks Marius,